# CSS - top property

Tags: css, properties

In CSS, Is the top property related to the top of the page, or the top of the parent element? 
If not the top of the parent element, is there some property attached to it?

Comment: It may be a little hard to parse, but I highly recommend reading the actual spec at http://w3.org/tr/css21/visuren.html#propdef-position (watch out in particular for 'containing block').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSS/top definition](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/top)

**For absolutely positioned elements:**
This property specifies the distance between the top margin edge of the element and the top edge of its containing block.

**For relatively positioned elements:**
This property specifies the offset is with respect to the top edges of the box itself.

Answer (score 0):

The 'top' property refers to the element's top offset from its nearest positioned parent, if the element itself is positioned absolute. If an element is positioned with relative positioning, the top property indicates the top offset of where the element would regularly render. So an element with a relative position with a top of 2px, for instance, would appear 2 pixels lower than where it would otherwise render.

I don't think I really understand your question though, can you ask it in another way?